# How to find FIRST and FOLLOW set of a recursive grammar?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Suppose I have the following CFG:

> S->aACD|BcAe
>
> A->b | EPSILON
>
> B->cf | d
>
> C->fe

Now I apply the FIRST rule on the CFG:

> FIRST(S)=FIRST(aAcd) U FIRST(BcAe)
>
> ={a} U FIRST(BcAe)
>
> = {a} U FIRST(B)-{EPSILON} U FIRST(cAe)
>
> = {a} U FIRST(B)-{EPSILON} U {c}
>
> = {a} U FIRST(Cf) U FIRST(d) -{EPSILON} U {c}
>
> = {a,f,d,c,EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(A)=FIRST(b) U FIRST(EPSILON)= ={B,EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(B)=FIRST(Cf) U FIRST(d)={d,f}
>
> FIRST(C)=FIRST(fe)={F}

Now I apply the FOLLOW rule on the CFG:

> FOLLOW(S)={$}
>
> FOLLOW(A)={c,e}
>
> FOLLOW(B)={c}
>
> FOLLOW(C)={f}

Is there any wrong? If it is wrong please show me how to do it.

Comment: "have I done my homework correctly?" is not a good match with Stack overflow. If you have a specific question relating to the algorithm, you might try asking it, although it is highly likely that such a question would be out of scope for SO, since it has little or nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @SourodipKundu  It's wrong. Its not the answer.

Comment: @SourodipKundu please check if the production is same as the one in my question.And Since `C` is in the body of production S->aACD ,`FOLLOW(C)` is `FIRST(D)`. Since `FIRST(D)` is `EPSILON` replace `D` in production `S->aACD` by `EPSILON`. So it become `S->aAC` then take `FOLLOW(C)` then it becomes `FOLLOW(S)` which is `$`. I think you lack basics please refer video that i suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Billa yes I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work above (question) suggest that you are not good in basic concepts. So you can make use of the [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uSlP91jmTM).

Grammer :

> S->aACD|BcAe
>
> A->b | EPSILON
>
> B->cf | d
>
> C->fe

No production means EPSILON so,

> D-> EPSILON

On applying first rule :

> FIRST(A)=FIRST(b) U FIRST(EPSILON)= ={b,EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(B)=FIRST(cf) U FIRST(d)={c} U {d} = {c,d}
>
> FIRST(C)=FIRST(fe)={f}
>
> FIRST(D)={EPSILON}
>
> FIRST(S)=FIRST(aACD) U FIRST(BcAe)
>
> ={a} U FIRST(BcAe)
>
> = {a} U FIRST(B)
>
> = {a} U {c,d}
>
> = {a,c,d}

on applying follow rule :

> FOLLOW(S)={$}
>
> FOLLOW(A)= FIRST(C) U FIRST(e) = {f,e}
>
> FOLLOW(B)={c}
>
> FOLLOW(C)={$}
>
> FOLLOW(D)={$}

Comment: Feel free to ask your doubts.

Comment: How the FOLLOW(C) became $ but Using the FIRST AND FOLLOW rule I get C follow f @Billa